# Is there a way to execute a command after Python turtle goes past a certain coordinate?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I have a code here that changes turtle to a ball and allows the user to move a ball around.

I want it to change background colors when the ball's x value decreases from (30,0) but is there a way to do this?
if possible, i want the background color to change back to white if the ball's x value rises past 30 again.

```
# import turtle setup
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
TURTLE_SIZE = 200

# functions
def go_left():
    x = t.xcor()
    if x > TURTLE_SIZE - 576:
        x -= 5
        t.setx(x)
    screen.update()

def go_right():
    x = t.xcor()
    if x < 576 - TURTLE_SIZE:
        x += 5
        t.setx(x)
    screen.update()

def go_up():
    y = t.ycor()
    if y < 576 - TURTLE_SIZE:
        y += 5
        t.sety(y)
    screen.update()

def go_down():
    y = t.ycor()
    if y < 576 - TURTLE_SIZE:
        y -= 5
        t.sety(y)
    screen.update()

# screen
screen = Screen()
screen.setup(1152,648)
screen.tracer(0)

t = Turtle()
t.shape("circle")
t.speed("slow")
t.color("blue")
t.penup()
t.setx(338)
t.sety(0)
screen.update()

# Keyboard (listeners)
screen.onkeypress(go_left, "Left")
screen.onkeypress(go_down, "Down")
screen.onkeypress(go_up, "Up")
screen.onkeypress(go_right, "Right")
screen.listen()
screen.mainloop()

if x < 30 - TURTLE_SIZE:
    screen.bgcolor("darkred")
```

Comment: you have to run it before `mainloop` but it may need to run timer to check it periodically. It would be simpler to check it directly in functions `go_left`, `go_right`

Answer (score 0):

According to official turtle's documentation, [`turtle.pos()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.pos) returns the current coordinates of turtle. Maybe you could check the coordinate with an `if` after each movement?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```py
# import turtle setup
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
TURTLE_SIZE = 200

# functions
def change_color():
    x = t.xcor()
    if x < 30 - TURTLE_SIZE:
        screen.bgcolor("darkblue")
    else:
        screen.bgcolor("White")
def go_left():
    x = t.xcor()
    if x > TURTLE_SIZE - 576:
        x -= 5
        t.setx(x)
    screen.update()
    change_color()

def go_right():
    x = t.xcor()
    if x < 576 - TURTLE_SIZE:
        x += 5
        t.setx(x)
    screen.update()
    change_color()

def go_up():
    y = t.ycor()
    if y < 576 - TURTLE_SIZE:
        y += 5
        t.sety(y)
    screen.update()

def go_down():
    y = t.ycor()
    if y < 576 - TURTLE_SIZE:
        y -= 5
        t.sety(y)
    screen.update()

# screen
screen = Screen()
screen.setup(1152,648)
screen.tracer(0)

t = Turtle()
t.shape("circle")
t.speed("slow")
t.color("blue")
t.penup()
t.setx(338)
t.sety(0)
screen.update()

# Keyboard (listeners)
screen.onkeypress(go_left, "Left")
screen.onkeypress(go_down, "Down")
screen.onkeypress(go_up, "Up")
screen.onkeypress(go_right, "Right")
screen.listen()
screen.mainloop()
```

#### What is added inside this code.

1. I added a function name `change_color` and call it every time any key is pressed using the [`lambda`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-lambda-anonymous-functions-filter-map-reduce/) function.
2. `screen.color` gives you error because it is `screen.bgcolor()`

Comment: it would look better if you would run `change_color()` directly inside functions `go_left()`, `go_down()`, `go_up()`, `go_rigth()`

Comment: @furas You're right, But I don't think it makes something different in my code. But I am changing it, Thanks...

Comment: result wil be the same but using list to execute many functions is rather not preffered. Similar is with using `or` for this `lambda: func1() or func2()`

Answer (score 0):

You should check it directly in `go_left`, `go_right`

```
def go_left():
    x = t.xcor()
    if x > TURTLE_SIZE - 576:
        x -= 5
        t.setx(x)

    if x < 30 - TURTLE_SIZE:
        screen.bgcolor("darkred")
    else:
        screen.bgcolor("white")
        
    screen.update()

def go_right():
    x = t.xcor()
    if x < 576 - TURTLE_SIZE:
        x += 5
        t.setx(x)

    if x < 30 - TURTLE_SIZE:
        screen.bgcolor("darkred")
    else:
        screen.bgcolor("white")

    screen.update()
```

You can reduce it and in `go_left` change color to `darkred` and in `go_right` to `white` (using `>=` instead of `<`)

```
def go_left():
    x = t.xcor()
    if x > TURTLE_SIZE - 576:
        x -= 5
        t.setx(x)

    if x < 30 - TURTLE_SIZE:
        screen.bgcolor("darkred")
        
    screen.update()

def go_right():
    x = t.xcor()
    if x < 576 - TURTLE_SIZE:
        x += 5
        t.setx(x)

    if x >= 30 - TURTLE_SIZE:
        screen.bgcolor("white")

    screen.update()
```

---

**EDIT:**

Both versions change background in every move - if you want to reduce it then you can remebere current color in global variable and run `bgcolor()` only when new color is different than current color.

```
current_backgroud = "white"  # global variable with default value at start

def go_left():
    global current_backgroud
    
    x = t.xcor()
    if x > TURTLE_SIZE - 576:
        x -= 5
        t.setx(x)

    if (x < 30 - TURTLE_SIZE) and (current_backgroud != "darkred"):
        current_backgroud = "darkred"
        screen.bgcolor("darkred")
        
    screen.update()

def go_right():
    global current_backgroud
    
    x = t.xcor()
    if x < 576 - TURTLE_SIZE:
        x += 5
        t.setx(x)

    if (x >= 30 - TURTLE_SIZE) and (current_backgroud != "white"):
        current_backgroud = "white"
        screen.bgcolor("white")

    screen.update()
```

---

**EDIT:**

You can use it to creaet many areas in different colors.

`go_left` and `go_right` need `if/else` in different order because one use `<` and other `>=`

```
current_backgroud = "white"  # global variable with default value at start

def go_left():
    global current_backgroud
    
    x = t.xcor()
    if x > TURTLE_SIZE - 576:
        x -= 5
        t.setx(x)

    if x < 30 - TURTLE_SIZE:
        new_color = "darkred"
    elif x < 130 - TURTLE_SIZE:
        new_color = "red"
    elif x < 230 - TURTLE_SIZE:
        new_color = "yellow"
    else:
        new_color = "white"
        
    if new_color != current_backgroud:
        current_backgroud = new_color
        screen.bgcolor(new_color)
        
    screen.update()

def go_right():
    global current_backgroud
    
    x = t.xcor()
    if x < 576 - TURTLE_SIZE:
        x += 5
        t.setx(x)

    if x >= 230 - TURTLE_SIZE:
        new_color = "white"
    elif x >= 130 - TURTLE_SIZE:
        new_color = "yellow"
    elif x >= 30 - TURTLE_SIZE:
        new_color = "red"
    else:
        new_color = "darkred"
        
    if new_color != current_backgroud:
        current_backgroud = new_color
        screen.bgcolor(new_color)

    screen.update()
```